# List of usefull calculation rules when performing an induction proof.

Tags: induction

I have recently gone into studying induction. I am having trouble in general performing such a proof and it is not so much that i dont understand what the induction is about but more the problem that I get the feeling that I don't posses the tools to perform such a proof.

example. I have seen in one induction example stating:  `floor[log(m) +1] = floor[log(m)+log(2)]` and i am sure there is a logical calculation rule supporting this fact but i just dont know it and lots of others. Yet!

So i was hoping you guys could point me to an already existing set of rules that one will find very usefull when performing induction(rewriting algorithms) or help me create one here.

Comment: If the context was algorithms, the logarithm in that statement was probably a logarithm base $2$, in which case the statement merely uses the fact that $\log_bb=$ for any base. \\ Your question really has nothing to do with induction: proofs by induction don’t necessarily even involve calculations in the sense that you have in mind. They appear in all areas of mathematics, and as a result, what you’re asking for is impossible: there’s simply too much ground to cover.

Comment: So what you are saying Brian is that I should give up if god haven't gifted me with the ability to see these things on my own? I find that hard to believe. All mathmaticians must have started somewhere.

Comment: No, I am not saying anything of the kind. I’m saying that you’re asking for something that doesn’t exist.